# Firebase listener behaves differently in APK than in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, apk, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I am building an app where the app listens for firebase updates and responds. My app runs perfectly fine when it's run in debug mode from Android Studio, but when I build a signed APK and run it from my phone, it doesn't work right.

Specifically, this bit of code:

```
weightListener = weights.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                weightVals = dataSnapshot.getValue(TrainingWeights.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                message.setText("Weight event listener error");
            }

        });
```

The TrainingWeights class has 2 fields: a List of Doubles, and an int value. In the Android Studio build, everything updates properly, but when it's run as an APK from a mobile device, the int value always returns 0, regardless of what the actual value is. I tried changing it to an object class like Integer, but when I do that it simply always returns 'undefined' (It still works properly in Android Studio). I don't know what is causing the problem, especially since I have other listeners in my code that aren't having any problem.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[id]"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the TrainingWeights class:

```
public class TrainingWeights {
    List<Double> weights;
    int iteration;

    public TrainingWeights(){

    }

    public List<Double> getWeights(){
        return weights;
    }

    public void setWeights(List<Double> weightValues){
        weights = weightValues;
    }

    public int getCurrentIteration(){
        return iteration;
    }

    public void setCurrentIteration(int iteration){
        this.iteration = iteration;
    }


}
```

Comment: When you build your signed APK, are you running Proguard?  If so, did you use the configuration in the [Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)?

Comment: I am not running Proguard. Do you think running it would fix the issue?

Comment: No, running it will not help. If you run it, you must configure it correctly to avoid having your POJO classes obfuscated.

Comment: Can you post your module build.gradle to allow us to see what the differences are between your debug and release versions?

Comment: Can you also post the relevant class (with field declarations) and the TrainingWeights class.

Comment: Hopefully I added all the relevant info.

Comment: There might be some issue with your Google play services, it requires version > 9.0 .

Comment: I have version 9.4.52

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but it's not good practice to mix the legacy SDK, `firebase-client-android:2.5.1+`,  with the new SDK `firebase-database:9.0.0`. Remove `firebase-client-android:2.5.1+` from your build, update your code as needed, and see if you get better results.